# And operator in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with special marks in string and I want to delete them.

here is my string:

```
let message='Hello my name is /# Jane #/, if from /# company#/'. Could you please call me back .
```

now I'm trying to delete this /#---#/ marks

```
message.replace(/#/g, "")
```

but how add "AND" operator in regex to delete '/' too.

Comment: Do you always have them paired? What if there is a "wild" `/#` at the end of the string?

Answer (score 3):

Or, more specific (replace `/#` or `#/`):

```
message.replace(/\/#|#\//g, "")
```

(You have to escape the `/` with `\/`)

Another more complex approach, which might or might not work depending on your use cases:

```js
let message = 'Hello my name is /# Jane #/, if from /# company#/. Could you please call me back.';
// replace in pairs and take care of extra whitespace
let regex = /\/#\s*(\w+)\s*#\//g;
message = message.replace(regex, "$1");
console.log(message);
```

Comment: You should use `\S` instead of `\w`, I think

Answer (score -1):

Use a character class:

```
message.replace(/[#\/]/g, "")
```

```js
let message='Hello my name is /# Jane #/, if from /# company#/. Could you please call me back .';
console.log(message.replace(/[#\/]/g, ""));
```

If you want to remove character `#` and `/` only when they are close together, use the following, it also replaces extra spaces

```js
let message='Hello my name is /# Jane #/, if from /# company#/. Could you please call me back .';
console.log(message.replace(/\/#\s*|\s*#\//g, ""));
```

Comment: That will also remove all occurrences of `#` and `/` everywhere.

Comment: @Styx: True, but it's not really clear in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I disagree. OP said _"I'm trying to delete this /#---#/ marks"_, not "I'm trying to remove all `#` and `/`".